# website down with php error

Tags: php, wordpress

i do not know php but had installed wordpress, i visit my site and see the following error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98304 bytes) in E:\Domains\mysite.com\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\wordfence\lib\wfLog.php on line 431
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 98304 bytes) in E:\Domains\mysite.com\wwwroot\wp-content\plugins\wordfence\lib\wfLog.php on line 431
```

how do i fix hat above, please guide

Comment: I think your device has no space left! and your logfiles are too big! check the size of the logfiles

Comment: Please follow the instructions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP)

Answer (score 2):

You have a plugin called Wordfence which is causing the problem. It appears to be overloading your memory. I wouldn't mess with your server config, the problem is with the plugin. Try deleting those logs, that should work, but it may only be a temporary solution. Removing the plugin would certainly solve the problem. No idea what Wordfence is though. If that doesn't work, change the title of your question to include "Wordfence plugin".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion i have got a better solution for you. All you need to do is just to increase memory size.

By default, when you installed and configure Wordpress it comes by 16MB memory . In your case, you can keep the plugin you already installed and add the following one line code to your **wp-config.php** file.

You can access this file via FTP(File Transfer Protocol) client FileZilla or from your hosting cPanel.

/* Increase memory */
code : define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );

Comment: This MIGHT work. Worth a try... although many hosts won't allow you to modify memory limits, it may cause your site to crash, and since the problem seems to be a log file growing out of control, it may simply be a bandaid on a growing problem.